# Missing value or infinity using nls in R

Tags: r, model, polynomials, nls

I have found similar posts but the solutions did not work for me. 
I want to fit a curve to some data. I expect the curve to be defined by a function similar to: 
y = -10*(x-0.3)^2 +1

When I use nls as follows:

```r
fit.2<-nls(co2 ~ F * (mvol+G)^k + C, data=soildata, start=list(F=-1, G=-0.25, C = 1, k=2))
lines(newdat$mvol, predict(fit.2, newdata = newdat), col="red", lwd=2)
```

I get the error:

```r
> fit.2<-nls(co2 ~ F * (mvol+G)^k + C, data=soildata, start=list(F=-1, G=-0.25, C = 1, k=2))
Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
  Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
```

I've tried adjusting the starting points but doesnt seem to help. I'm new to R but have some experience with matlab.

Let me know if you see whats wrong.

Here's what my data looks like.

[image]

Comment: So your eqn is `y = F * (mvol + G)^k + C` and you are fitting `F`, `G`, `k`, and `C` as parameters?  It seems strange to me that you are fitting `k` as a parameter--your text suggests maybe just fixing `k = 2`, which seems reasonable. Powers have **strong** effects, so it's common to log everything if you're not sure what the power is, which will make the estimation a little more robust.

Comment: This is great. You're right I should just fix the exponent at 2.